# How to exclude elements with certain attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got many checkboxes like

```
<input type="checkbox" disabled="disabled" class="item-store">
```

With jQuery, I can select them like that:

```
$('input.item-store:checkbox')
```

I would like to exclude those which are not enabled. The following doesn't seem to work:

```
$('input.item-store[disabled!="disabled"]:checkbox')
// or
$('input[disabled!="disabled"].item-store:checkbox')
```

With the above query, I still get those which are disabled... Can you give me a tipp?

sl3dg3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do

```
$('input.item-store:checkbox:not(:disabled)')
```

Comment: :)  or (just figured out): $(`input.item-store:checkbox:enabled`)